# Taylor Series of trigonometric function

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

I searched quite a bit online but could only find the MACLAURIN SERIES of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$:

$$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots$$

$$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!}+\cdots$$

Can anyone explain how we can express the TAYLOR SERIES of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, and also show me the derivation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maclaurin series = Taylor series around $x=0$.

Comment: Maclaurin series is the taylor series centered at 0. To find the general Taylor series replace every $x$ with $(x-c)$

Comment: @Biggs Not quite so easy as that as $\sin(c)$ and $\cos(c)$ aren't necessarily $=0,\pm 1$ for any arbitrary $c$.

Comment: @Biggs and don't forget to evaluate all your $f^{(n)}$ at $c$ instead of $0$.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_Series_Expansion_for_Sine_Function) helps

Comment: Yes, you all are correct. I worded that incorrectly. I was referring to the general form of a Taylor Series, not the given one. I can see how that is incredibly misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint/Partial Solution:**
Recall the definition of the Taylor Series formula at a point $a$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$$
(Note that $f^{(k)}(a)$ is a short-hand for the $k$th derivative of $f(x)$ evaluated at $a$)

Letting $f(x)=\sin x$, we note that the numerator of the fraction is the following cycle:
$$\sin(c), \cos(c), -\sin(c), -\cos(c), \cdots$$
The rest is just going to be expanding the series. It won't condense well if $a$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$ though. The same logic follows for the cosine expansion. As an example of this, let $x=1$. Then we get the following series:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\sin^{(k)}(1)}{k!}(x-1)^k$$
Expanded, this becomes
$$\sin(1)+(x-1) \cos(1)-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2 \sin(1)-\frac 16 (x-1)^3 \cos(1)+\frac{1}{24} (x-1)^4 \sin(1)+\cdots$$
After seeing this, you might think to yourself that this could be broken up into a sum without any derivative symbols. That hypothetical you is right! We can rewrite this as
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin(1)(-1)^k}{(2k)!}(x-1)^{2k}+\frac{\cos(1)(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+1)!}(x-1)^{2k+1}\right)$$ 
A similar formula emerges for the cosine expansion, but I leave that up to the OP!

Comment: Could you have accidentally used "n" instead of "k" in your answer? I don't quite gete where the n comes from

Comment: @javabeginner_0101 yes, good catch. Threw that together a little quickly I suppose! I'll fix that

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
\sin x =&\ \sin(x-a+a) = \sin(x-a) \cos a +\cos(x-a) \sin a\\
=&\ \cos a \sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^n\frac{(x-a)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} + \sin a\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{(x-a)^{2n}}{(2n)!}.
\end{align}

I will leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out the Taylor expansion for $\cos x$ at $x=a$.

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor expansion of any function about any point can be found by replacing $x$ with $x-c$, assuming you want a $c$-centered expansion. You also would need to evaluate your derivatives at this point $c$ as opposed to zero. Check the general formula for a Taylor expansion.